# Include_path in php.ini

Tags: php, pear

I'm trying to send mail using PEAR framework (and WAMP).

I installed PEAR and package MAIL and it is in correct folder. Problem is with include_path in php.ini.

When I checked where is my php.ini (php --ini), I have result:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
>
> Loaded Configuration File: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.ini
>
> Scan for additional .ini files in:
>
> Additional .ini files parsed:

In C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.ini I set:

```
include_path = ".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear"
```

And I restarded WAMP.

After click button to send mail, I have following error:

> Warning: include(Mail.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\send_mail.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mail.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\send_mail.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in C:\wamp\www\send_mail.php on line 45

No idea, why include_path is here '.;C:\php\pear'.

Comment: did u restart yr wamp server??

Comment: Look at your `phpinfo()` to know exactly what ini file(s) are being used. The file may differ between cli and apache calls (`php --ini` is misleading)

Comment: You maybe also need some sort of PEAR autoloader, which searches in subdirectories to `…/pear/`.

Comment: Mike B, thank you a lot for your help. As you say, phpinfo() show another path than php --ini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike B told me to look at your phpinfo() to know exactly what ini file(s) are being used. The file was differ between cli and apache calls (php --ini is misleading).